# Displaying tangents as colors

Tags: materials, game-engine

I'm trying to view tangents used in sceneview and that will be exported.
I found two options:

- Using cycles material:

[geometry](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/geometry.html) or just tangent-node
but both doesn't work - i got only black screen. (Normals work great)

- Using glsl shader in BGE:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Blender/Lighting_of_Bumpy_Surfaces but `shader.setAttrib(bge.logic.SHD_TANGENT)` doesnt work(same tangent for entire mesh). I also can view everything except tangents :(

So, maybe I miss some ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, tangents successfully appears in shader when I switched viewport shading to "Material".

Testing code:

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

VertexShader = """
    attribute vec4 tangent;
    varying vec4 frag_tangent;
    void main()
    {
        frag_tangent = tangent;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    }
"""

FragmentShader = """
    varying vec4 frag_tangent;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = frag_tangent;
    }
"""

mesh = cont.owner.meshes[0]
for mat in mesh.materials:
    shader = mat.getShader()
    if shader != None:
        if not shader.isValid():
            shader.setSource(VertexShader, FragmentShader, 1)
shader.setAttrib(bge.logic.SHD_TANGENT)
```

It works great when viewport is in right shading mode.

Thanks :)